# Removing brackets and inverted quotations when writing a list to a csv file PYTHON

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, csv

I'm currently writing a list to a csv file. I have done that correctly. 
(Hypothetically) my work looks something like this:

```
stuff = [34,87,34,43,23,32]
with open("typer.txt", "w") as myTyper:
    myTyperSpells = csv.writer(myTyper)
    myTyperSpells.writerow([stuff])
```

This list is successfully written to the text file "typer". However, it  appears like this:

```
"[34, 87, 34, 42, 23, 32]"
```

Is it possible to remove the inverted commas, square brackets and spaces so that it appears like this in the text file instead?:

```
34,87,34,42,23,32
```

Any help will be useful...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the square brackets around `stuff` when you write the row.

E.g.

```
myTyperSpells.writerow(stuff)
```

As it is you're putting your list inside another list

Comment: Thanks-I didn't realise it was that simple! :D